# Probability Estimate for different class using supervised classification with neural network training

Tags: machine-learning, keras, classification, tensorflow2.0, supervised-learning

In the tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification

at

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification#make_predictions

> A prediction is an array of 10 numbers. They represent the model's
>   "confidence" that the image corresponds to each of the 10 different
>   articles of clothing. You can see which label has the highest
>   confidence value:

Instead of confidence, if I want to estimate the probability of each class (different articles of clothing). How will I do that?

Comment: What you actually get are indeed the probabilities - notice that the word confidence is quoted.

Comment: Okay, I didn't that they are the same thing. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: *I didn't know that they are the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @desertnaut mention a comment, above, the confidence in the code

```
probability_model = tf.keras.Sequential([model, 
                                         tf.keras.layers.Softmax()])
predictions = probability_model.predict(test_images)
```

given by the variable `predictions` are indeed probability.